# Conditionally Insert Data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form using which I want the user to be able to insert records into the database and also edit them.The update query works fine, but when a field in the form is left empty, it replaces the already existing data in that specific field with a `NULL` or blank value, so it replaces the existing data.

How do I set the form to allow it to insert one field at a time without replacing existing records with `NULL`?

This is my `HTML` form:

```
<form action="saveprofile.php" method="post">
          <p class="text-muted">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"name="shortbio" id="shortbio" >
          </p>
          <hr>  
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Long Bio" name="longbio" id="longbio"></textarea>
          </p>  
                <hr>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location" >

            </form>
```

And my update query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET
shortbio='$shortbio',longbio='$longbio',location='$location'
WHERE 
user_id=$user_id LIMIT 1";
```

The update query works perfect.But now since i have not set each filled to required,when i fill in one section of the form and leave the others blank,then existing records in the existing fields in the database table are replaced with null.

Comment: Can you not check for `NULL`/empty values and then conditionally insert them only if they exist?

Comment: yes,thats the perfect solution.But i dont know how to do that,Im new to php/mysql

Comment: Just fill existing values back into the form values. this way values in the database will be replaced with same data.

Comment: this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read up about that and use parameterised queries. Otherwise a malicious user can corrupt your data, or worse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each input value of form through if/else condition. After that you need to generate/execute database query accordingly. Like in update query you will select only these column whom value was given in HTML form. If value was not given then you will not select these column in update query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET ";
if(!empty($_GET['shortbio'])){
        $shortbio = $_GET['shortbio'] ;    
        $sql .= "shortbio='$shortbio', ";
}

if(!empty($_GET['longbio'])){
        $longbio = $_GET['longbio'] ;    
        $sql .= "longbio='$longbio', ";
}

if(!empty($_GET['location'])){
        $location = $_GET['location'] ;    
        $sql .= "location='$location', ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ','); //Remove additional comma
$sql .= "WHERE user_id=$user_id LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: so i guess in this instance what you are suggesting is:if{ shortbio='$shortbio' set shortbio='$shortbio'} im struggling with the syntax

Comment: @AngelaDutchan Please check updated answer. I have added code in it.

Comment: There is one problem in this , that it will leave the last extra comma (,) in the query , so need to sanitize it in the final query

Comment: @VikasUmrao I have updated code, i have added rtrim($sql, ',') which will remove additional comma.

Comment: @Shujaat its great

Answer (score 0):

Just repopulate the form data like this :

```
 <?php 
    $sql= "select * from table";
    $result=mysqli_query($sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    ?>


         <form action="saveprofile.php" method="post">
                 <p class="text-muted">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control"name="shortbio" id="shortbio" value="<?php echo $row['col_name']?>" >
                  </p>
            </form>
```